# In an asp.net, how to get a reference of a custom webcontrol from a usercontrol?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, web-parts

I have a page which holds a custom webcontrol and a usercontrol. I need to reference of webcontrol in usercontrol class. So, I make the declaration of webcontrol as public in page class. But, when I do “this.Page.”, I don’t see the webcontrol listed in list provided by intellisense. Most probably, I am missing something.

In an asp.net page, how to  get a reference of a custom webcontrol from  a usercontrol?

Please advise. Thanks
Pankaj

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better of making a method on the UserControl which accept an argument of your WebControl.

Then let the Page wire them up together.

Having a Usercontrol relying on Page.FindControl seems very much like a hack to me.

E.g. Something like this in your UserControl:

```
public void SetWebControl(MyWebControl control)
{
// Do whatever
}
```

And in your Page you'd do this:

```
override OnInit()
{
this.MyUserControl1.SetWebControl(MyWebControl1);
}
```

It's all pseudo code ofc :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the ID of the webcontrol, you can just do:

```
Control ctrl = Page.FindControl (ID_of_the_webcontrol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get control at the page with FindControl method :

```
Control yourUserControl = this.Page.FindControl("yourControlsID");
```

The Page class is the instance of your page, it's an instance of the base class `System.Web.UI.Page`. So you can't get the public property with Page unless you cast it to your page class' type.